# Is there a way to get folder's creation date in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I tried with NSFileManager's attributesOfItemAtPath. It works well with files, but not with folders. Although in [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html), they claimed it should work either on file or folder. But all I get is a nil value if I call this on folders.

Code I use:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSDictionary *folderAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:somePath error:nil];

NSLog(@"Creation date: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[folderAttributes objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate]]);
```

The output is always null to me. My "somePath" is an NSString, with a format like this:

```
file://localhost/Users/username/...
```

Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's a path, don't use a URL. Use a path:

```
/Users/username/dir
```

Also, get used to the error parameter, it's really helpful.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *attr = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&error];
if (error)
    NSLog(@"%@", error) /* at least */
```

It will help you. And if for some reason you don't want it, notice the parameter is a pointer to object, so you may want to use `NULL` instead of `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

`somePath` should be formatted as a straight POSIX path - set it to /Users/username/... - that should work.